# generalizar el nombre de un pdf para leerlo con python

Tags: python

Necesito saber como puedo leer cualquier documento pdf en python, me explico tengo un script para leer un pdf, pero debo ponerle el nombre del pdf, existe alguna manera para generalizar este nombre y pueda leer el pdf sin importar que  nombre tenga?... espero haberme explicado bien, se agradece la ayuda.

Comment: Te invito a leer [ask] para que sepas como realizar preguntas y que así tu pregunta sea bien recibida por la comunidad, también te invito a ver [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del sitio, Podrías compartir el código de lo que tienes hasta ahora para que sea más fácil ayudarte con lo que quieres hacer?

Comment: Mejora tu pregunta. Tienes los nombres en una lista? No tienes nada? Quieres abrir toda una carpeta con PDFs? No podemos ayudarte si no especificas bien el problema